# How to remove single package from cache/nix store?

Tags: nixos, nix

Is there any way to force removing a package from `/nix/store/..`

I am testing my expression for my package and want to make sure it will rebuild correctly.

The problem is if I build my package once, the next time I build it again it will use the cache.

I use this command to test my package

```
nix-shell -I nixpkgs=</path/to/repo> -p <package_name>
```

I don't want to use `nix-collect-garbage` because it remove lot of `buildInputs` too.

Looking for something like `nix-cg <package_name>`

Comment: while Vladimir is right, you can achive what you want with `--check` argument, for example, `nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A hello --check` will rebuild `hello` even if it is available in cache

Comment: @danbst Exactly what I needed, thanks again! Was looking for a way to re-compile packages, and opened this thread because of an unrelated question. Pretty frustrating though that `--check` is not listed as an option under `nix-build` man page (nor under `nix-instantiate`'s), and only found it under `nix-store`'s by accident... (I guess that's why it works with `nix-shell` as well.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`nix-store --delete /path`  Note that the path might be alive and thus refused to be deleted without `--ignore-liveness` and root privileges.

Comment: sudo nix-store --delete --ignore-liveness /nix/store/XXX

Comment: Careful with that! I just recursively deleted my entire system and had to recover from the install USB.

Comment: This command borked my $HOME user profile symlinks to store, despite the package I was uninstalling was `android-studio` I thought was ok.

Comment: Looks like there may be a newer version: `nix store delete`: https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/new-cli/nix3-store-delete.html